# How to find longest consistent increment in a python list?

Tags: python-2.7

```
possible_list = []
bigger_list = []

new_list= [0, 25, 2, 1, 14, 1, 14, 1, 4, 6, 6, 7, 0, 10, 11]
for i in range(0,len(new_list)):
   # if the next index is not greater than the length of the list
    if (i + 1) < (len(new_list)):
         #if the current value is less than the next value
         if new_list[i] <= new_list[i+1]:
             # add the current value to this sublist
             possible_list.append(new_list[i])
             # if the current value is greater than the next, close the list and append it to the lager list
         bigger_list.append(possible_list)
print bigger_list
```

How do I find the longest consistent increment in the list called `new_list`?
I expect the result to be

```
[[0,2], [2], [1,14], [1,14], [1,4,6,6,7], [0,10,11]]
```

I can find the remaining solution from there myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Longest increasing subsequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992697/longest-increasing-subsequence)

Comment: that is usually called the longest increasing subsequence.

Comment: Shouldn't the first element be `[0,25]`?

Comment: @tobias_k      Thanks for the correction. it was a typographical error.

Comment: @AmiTavory the solution tobias_k gave is simple and straightforward. Kudos to him.

Comment: @ebenezerpopoola What does the quality of an answer have to do with the issue of whether your question is a duplicate?

Comment: @AmiTavory This is not the same problem. Longest increasing subsequence can be non-continuous, this one is about continuous non-increasing segments of the list.

Comment: @tobias_k OK, that is relevant - I missed that. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem (but not the only one) with your code is that you are always adding the elements to *the same* `possible_list`, thus the lists in `bigger_list` are in fact all the same list!

Instead, I suggest using `[-1]` to access the last element of the list of subsequences (i.e. the one to append to) and `[-1][-1]` to access the last element of that subsequence (for comparing the current element to).

```
new_list= [0, 25, 2, 1, 14, 1, 14, 1, 4, 6, 6, 7, 0, 10, 11]    
subseq = [[]]
for e in new_list:
    if not subseq[-1] or subseq[-1][-1] <= e:
        subseq[-1].append(e)
    else:
        subseq.append([e])
```

This way, `subseq` ends up the way you want it, and you can use `max` to get the longest one.

```
>>> subseq
[[0, 25], [2], [1, 14], [1, 14], [1, 4, 6, 6, 7], [0, 10, 11]]
>>> max(subseq, key=len)
[1, 4, 6, 6, 7]
```

Comment: tobias_k thanks for the answer. you really understood the question well. you just made my day