# Counting how much number are in ascending order in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write function that will count how much numbers are ordered in ascending order in a row.
for example:
we have this list:

```
L = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 7, 5, 6]
```

and the largest ascending series of numbers are 5.

I've tried:

```
count=0
def ascord(L,count):
    for i in range(0,len(L)-1):
        if L[i]<L[i+1]:
            count+=1
    return count
```

but the output is 7. I don't know how to "reset" count so it wouldn't take [2,8] and [5,6] into consideration

Edit: I meant that if I for ex. add at the end of list twenty numbers in asc. order they will be largest series of numbers, so the first count should be set to 0, and start counting from start

PS. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Under what conditions should you "reset" count?

Comment: You want to reset when it breaks the "ascending" condition

Comment: keep a `max_count` variable, and `count` keeps current max ascending length if ascending monotony breaks compare `count` and `max_count`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find longest consistent increment in a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861515/how-to-find-longest-consistent-increment-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up:

```
def ascord(L):
    answer = 0
    count = 1
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        if L[i] < L[i + 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count > answer:
                answer = count
            count = 1
    return max(count, answer)

L = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 7, 5, 6]
print (ascord(L)) # 5
```

cheers :)

Comment: Because it didn't work, as your subsequent edit corroborates.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't see why the downvote should still be kept, now that the problem is fixed? Or is it from someone else?

Comment: Well, It doesn't work for me, now It returns 0. 
After changing list to:
L = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 7, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,123,124,125,126,12345,123541234,23465234632456,3456734567345672]

Comment: https://tio.run/##bVDRCoIwFH3fVxzoRXFBZlZE9QX@gfggNmsgm1yV6OvXNjUROoxdzs65517WfvqXVokxD1Gj7CpNjyALLwwWperegnDDztNKD6q3LPas1gQJqUCleoqgEcr2YYt4anaQNbJcFri6gghxsWhLYjRHOoimE2uTDRl992mhtbxa1Bv/jJgnkOgHUpOfscwK@Z7jwJFyHDlOHJYm/h7P2T86tWAtSZsV/H4pxAapMV8 Works fine for me

Comment: Oh I see why now. Since you need to check one final time at the end of the function

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

According to your logic, start with

```
count = 1
```

instead of

```
count = 0
```

Also, use an additional variable to keep track of the max count encountered so far, while traversing through the list. 
Reset count to 1 when the ascent breaks.

```
def ascord(L):
    count, ans = 1, 1     
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        if L[i]<L[i+1]:
            count+=1
        else:
            count=1
        ans = max(count, ans)
    return ans
```

Answer (score 1):

With `groupby` you can find the longest sequence of elements that sort ascending:

```
L = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 7, 5, 6]

from itertools import groupby 

sorted_seq=[]
for k,v in groupby(zip(L, L[1:]), key=lambda t:t[0]<t[1]):
    if k==True: 
        temp=list(v)
        sorted_seq.append([t[0] for t in temp]+[temp[-1][1]])

>>> sorted_seq
[[2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3], [2, 8], [5, 6]]
```

Then take the `max` of that with `len` as a key:

```
>>> max(sorted_seq, key=len)
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Then:

```
>>> len(max(sorted_seq, key=len))
5
```

Which (if you don't care about dropping the final element of the sorted sequence and adding 1 to compensate) can be a single comprehension:

```
>>> len(max(([t[0] for t in v] for k,v in groupby(zip(L, L[1:]), key=lambda t:t[0]<t[1]) if k), key=len))+1
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code instead counts the number of pairs in the list  `L` such that `L[i] < L[i + 1]`. The bug is that you do not track the continuity of ascending sub-sequence in the list. For example, while iteration over `L` if at some point a condition `L[i] >= L[i + 1]` occur then you should reset `count`. @Gareth Ma corrected your code. Although, below I have shared my code that will return you max length ascending subsequence in the list L.

Note, while iterating over the `L`, `cstart` and `cend` are index points for the current subsequence. Current subsequence grows until the current value `cval` greaser than previous `val` — keeps track of increasing value. At the end of each subsequence (either because of iteration exhaust or the current `cval` is smaller than previous `val`) I compare the lengths of subsequences and rests `start` and `end` indexes of longest subsequences in `L`.

```
def find_longest_ascending(L):
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L
    I = enumerate(L)
    cstart, val = next(I)
    start = end = cstart
    for cend, cval in I:
        if cval <= val:
            if end - start < cend - cstart:
               start, end = cstart, cend
            cstart = cend
        val = cval
    if end - start < cend - cstart + 1:
       start, end = cstart, cend + 1
    return L[start: end]
```

When the longest ascending subsequence is the suffix of the `L` (in if-condition outside the for-loop) the `cend` do not point out of subsequence hance added 1.

Answer (score -2):

Edited:

Inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149440/python-splitting-list-based-on-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence).

```
sub_lst = [0]+[i for i in range(1,len(L))  if L[i] < L[i-1] ]+[None]
print(max(len(x) for x in (L[b:e] for (b, e) in ((0,1) if sub_lst[1] == None else (sub_lst[i-1],sub_lst[i]) for i in range(1,len(sub_lst))))))
```

Unreadable, I know. Took it as a challenge :)

Comment: He literally asked for ascending sequence, not consecutive your code is counting. This is not answering the question.

Comment: And now the new version doesn't work either, since you don't reset the count everytime it breaks. take L=[1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6] for example.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Edited and should be working.

Comment: @GarethMa on [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6] your example your function returns 5, while it should had  return 6. Am I right?

Comment: No? Why 6... it asks for longest consecutive increasing subarray, which is 1,2,3,4,5 from the start...

Comment: I see. My mind stopped at " how much numbers are ordered in ascending order in a row"; my bad