# Python Longest Increasing Subsequence of Indexes in a Array

Tags: python

This algorithm (originally implemented in [unl-aligner](http://research.variancia.com/unl-aligner/)) calculates the longest list of increasing numbers with correspondingly increasing indices in the sequence, so given

```
seq = [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]
```

it will return

```
[0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15]
```

the implementation looks like

```
def subseq(seq, keyfn=lambda value: value):
    if not seq: return seq
    tail = []
    prev = []
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        for k in range(len(tail)-1, -1, -1):
            if keyfn(seq[tail[k]]) < keyfn(seq[i]):
                if len(tail) == k+1:
                    tail.append(i)
                elif keyfn(seq[tail[k+1]]) > keyfn(seq[i]):
                    tail[k+1] = i
                prev.append(tail[k])                    
                break
        else:
            tail.append(i)
            prev.append(None)

    i = tail[-1]
    subseq = [seq[i]]
    while prev[i] is not None:
        i = prev[i]
        subseq.append(seq[i])
    subseq.reverse()
    return subseq
```

The algorithm performs a linear scan, while a bisect (binary) search should be [preferred](https://www.rookieslab.com/posts/linear-search-vs-bisection-search-in-python).
Which is the best approach to refactor it to perform a binary search?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this more efficiently with a binary search vs. linear. The reason is because a binary search works on a sorted list, since you can compare adjacent elements. It's not obvious to me if that can be applied here.

Comment: How can you bisect something that isn't sorted? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: first sort your sequence / use `bisect` to keep the list sorted. Now you can apply binary search.

Comment: Also, your output is not the *longest increasing subsequence* - I'm not sure what that output represents.

Comment: @pault the result is the longest consecutive sequence of increasing integers numbers as you can see from the output.

Comment: @ggorlen that's a good point.

Comment: @loretoparisi none of the numbers in the output are consecutive. I *think* what you're describing is the longest list of increasing numbers in the sequence with correspondingly increasing indices in the sequence. Also your sample code fails because `tail` is undefined.

Comment: @pault you are right I mean the indexes. In fact those indexes represents words in the actual implementations (see the link). Correcting the code thanks, here it is a running example: https://repl.it/@loretoparisi/LongestIncreasingSubsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38337443/8291840) answer:

```
bisect = "longest_subsequence([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,2,2,2,2,5,1,7,8])"
_subseq = "subseq([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,2,2,2,2,5,1,7,8])"

from timeit import timeit

print(timeit(bisect, globals=globals(), number=10000))  # 0.2994734
print(timeit(_subseq, globals=globals(), number=10000))  # 0.32428109999999993
```

This is the result on a totally random test, for your example they seem almost exact time-wise